# how to only download the 1.7 JDK, not SDK, for windows

Tags: java

Installing java for casual java developers has always been something of a minefield.  E.g. do we need SE or EE edition for say STS/Grails, do we need the SDK or JDK?  I am pretty sure I need the JDK 1.7 for EE edition.  The question is, how do I get the JDK without the bloated SDK?  My understanding of the SDK it that its additional tools such as glassfish, something I have no need for.  Space on my SSD is a premium.

The oracle EE download page:

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html
```

only seems to allow you to download the JDK AND SDK, is there any way to install just the JDK?

I already have the 64 bit JDK installed, but sadly, STS only works with 32 bit (on windows).  Will these conflict when I install both?

Comment: There is no difference between SDK and JDK in Java. Your question remains unclear. Possible you're referring to the JRE, but it's anybody's guess.

Comment: download JDK here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Comment: @EJP, there is a significant difference between SDK and JDK.  SDK includes things like glassfish.  When you go for the SDK (the only option for EE java), you cannot opt-out of installing Glassfish for example.  I only want the JDK (not the SDK).

Comment: Don't get consufed, JDK and SDK are same, Before it was called SDK (more prominent during Sun's time), and later it was started calling JDK. The main source of confusion is the wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit#Ambiguity_between_a_JDK_and_an_SDK) , with paragraph `Ambiguity between a JDK and an SDK`

Comment: @Mustafa, there is significant difference between the two. I suggest you look at this page: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html  and you will see SDK and JDK are quite distinct.  Also look at this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166298/differences-between-jdk-and-java-sdk

Comment: @John, +1, Oracle is causing a lot of confusion. I still cannot find where to download only JDK EE 1.7, more than a year later. What's up with that? How can they suck so much?

Answer (score 14):

You can download JDK 7 [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html#jdk-7u80-oth-JPR)

The Java SDK and JDK are different you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166298/differences-between-jdk-and-java-sdk) difference between them

You can download any version of JDK from this [oracle archive](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html) link, To download older version of JDK please register in the on click on download link

Comment: Hi, I think I need the EE version of the JDK, not the SE version.  Anyone know where I can get only the JDK for the EE version?

Comment: First understand difference between SDK,JDK and Java EE HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024143/jdk-java-se-jdk-java-ee

Comment: You can download any version of java from oracle archive: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html,But you should signup in the oracle website to download older versions

Answer (score 2):

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4 is the reference implementation of the Java EE 7 specification. So you can never download Java EE itself like you do with Java SE by downloading the JDK, but you always download an application server implementing it.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24444454/1317559)