# Configuring the Eclipse IDE for using the Google Maps API

Tags: java, eclipse, google-maps-api-3, eclipse-plugin

I am working using the Google Maps API for the first time. I am using the `Eclipse IDE` for this development using the `Java` programming language.

The import Statements like import `com.google.code.geocoder.Geocoder;` are giving errors. I know Google APIs are not inbuilt in java. Please help me in solve this.

Answer (score 0):

did you followed :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

you will need an account and register the app but all the info is there :)

Comment: Hi, I am using JDK for development not SDK... Ithink this is not the procedure for it..!

Comment: :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166298/differences-between-jdk-and-java-sdk