# When exactly SDK is required

Tags: java, sdk

I joined a new project where we are building web applications but we are using jdk instead of sdk.

So when exactly SDK is required and can we develope web-apps using jdk as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differences between JDK and Java SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166298/differences-between-jdk-and-java-sdk)

Comment: JDK  (Java Development Kit) is an SDK (Software Development Kit). It is unclear what you're really asking.

Answer (score 0):

SDK is broader term which stands for Software Development Kit. Which can be used for any bundle of software(s) and libraries would be used for specific type of Application(s).

It can be for Android Application Development or some other type of application. So what I understand in your case your SDK actually have JDK in it's bundled libraries along with some other software(s) and libraries.